Unresolved reference: sourceCompatibility , Unresolved reference: targetCompatibility
Всем здравствуйте, пытаюсь сделать bild gradle для приложения проблема заключается в том что, когда я ставлю значение minSdk = 25, то Android Studio выдает ошибки:

Unresolved reference: sourceCompatibility


Unresolved reference: targetCompatibility


Expression 'testImplementation' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found


Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:public val NamedDomainObjectContainer<Configuration>.testImplementation: NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration> defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

Но когда я ставлю значение 34 или 35, то ошибки пропадают
Мне нужно чтобы приложение работало на android 7.1.1 и выше, но я не понимаю как это исправить, подскажите, пожалуйста. Буду очень признателен
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.application"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.application"
        minSdk = 25
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}


Так AS или Gradle эти ошибки пишет? AS часто глючит, важнее что Gradle при запуске сборки из командной строки говорит.
